# PrimeNG frozen column breaks after selecting row again

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am having an issue with the corresponding feature. I have amended primeNG frozen columns as per primeNG 13, I have been able to modify the table 2 (as shown below) which appears after selecting a row from table 1.
[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

This works fine when done the first time, however the table breaks when I select another row from table 1.
Below is the broken table 2 after selecing another row, without reloading the page:
[image: Broken table 2]

I would like to fix this issue where the frozen columns aligns itself to the right.

Below is my HTML file:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="selectedTransactionFile">
        <h4>Détails <small *ngIf="listOfTransactions">- {{listOfTransactions?.length}} transactions</small></h4>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p-table styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines p-datatable-striped p-datatable-sm" #dtDetails [loading]="listOfTransactionsLoading" [columns]="cols" [value]="listOfTransactions" 
                scrollDirection="both" [scrollable]="true"  [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50,100]">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                        <tr>
                            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pTooltip]="col.header" tooltipPosition="top"  pFrozenColumn [frozen]='col.frozen' [ngStyle]="{'width':col.width}">
                                {{col.header}}
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="filter-header-height" *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="true" [ngStyle]="{'width':col.width}"   pFrozenColumn [frozen]='col.frozen' >
                                <div class="p-fluid">
                                    <p-multiSelect *ngSwitchCase="col.field == 'state'" appendTo="body" [options]="states"
                                        [selectedItemsLabel] = "getSelectedLabels('{0}')"
                                        [style]="{ 'width': '100%'}" (onChange)="dtDetails.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in')"
                                        emptyFilterMessage="Aucune données" defaultLabel="Choisir"></p-multiSelect>
                                    <input class="filter-input-height" *ngSwitchCase="col.field != 'state' && col.field != 'action'" pInputText  type="text"  (input)="dtDetails.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')">
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row let-columns="columns">
                        <tr>
                            <td *ngFor="let col of columns"  [pTooltip]="row[col.field]" tooltipPosition="top" [escape]= "true"  pFrozenColumn [frozen]='col.frozen' [ngStyle]="{'width':col.width}">
                                
                                <div class="text-center" *ngIf="col.field === 'action' && row['state'] !== 'IGNORED' && row['state'] !== 'TREATED'">
                                    <button pButton type="button" label="Ignorer" (click)="onIgnore(row)"></button>
                                </div>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="displayTransactionDetails(row)" *ngIf="col.field === 'uid'">{{row[col.field]}}</a>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="onSelectTransaction(row)" *ngIf="col.field==='state'&& row['state']==='MISSING_ASSET'">{{row[col.field]}}</a>
                                <span *ngIf="(col.field!=='state'||row['state']!=='MISSING_ASSET')&&col.field !== 'uid'">{{row[col.field]}}</span>
                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage" let-columns let-frozen="frozen">
                        <tr>
                            <td [attr.colspan]="columns.length">
                                {{frozen ? 'Aucune données trouvées' : '&nbsp;'}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <strong style="float:left">#: {{dtDetails?.totalRecords}}</strong>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                </p-table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
```

Below is the code executed when i click on the row:

```
 onRowSelect(): void {
        this.listOfTransactionsLoading = true;
        this.resetDisplayTransactionDetails();
        this.transactionService
            .loadTransactionsByInternalFilename(this.selectedTransactionFile.filename)
            .subscribe(
                list => {
                    this.listOfTransactions = list;
                    this.listOfTransactionsLoading = false;
                    this.buildTableColumnsWithFields();
                },
                error => {
                    this.listOfTransactionsFilesLoading = false;
                    this.requestOnError(error);
                }
            );
    }

    private buildTableColumnsWithFields(): void {
        this.cols = [];
        if (this.listOfTransactions.length > 0) {
            for (const transaction of this.listOfTransactions) {
                Object.keys(transaction).forEach(key => {
                    if ('state;depositCode;deleted;'.indexOf(key) < 0) {
                        this.cols.push({field: key, header: key});
                    }
                });
            }
            const filterMap: Map<string, SelectItem> = new Map<string, SelectItem>();
            for (let i = 0; i < this.listOfTransactions.length; i++) {
                filterMap.set(this.listOfTransactions[i]['state'], {
                    label: this.listOfTransactions[i]['state'],
                    value: this.listOfTransactions[i]['state']
                });
            }
            this.states = Array.from(filterMap.values()).sort((a, b) =>
                a.label.localeCompare(b.label)
            );
            this.cols = Array.from(
                this.cols
                    .reduce((list, col) => list.set(col.field, col), new Map())
                    .values()
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe the `td` under `pTemplate="summary"` needs a `[attr.colspan]="columns.length"` instead of `colspan=3`

Comment: @TheFabio Thanks for the correction but it doesn't fix my problem. I have tried to remove ngSwitch which fixes the bad alignment but it removes my filter row. Is there an alternative to place my filter row conditions instead?